# Error compiling lwfinger's rtl8188eu driver for Realtek RTL8188EU

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, compiling, realtek-wireless

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with the wireless USB adapter Realtek RTL8188EUs.

Error when I type make in the cloned folder:

```
fossiscool@foss-is-cool:~/Área de Trabalho/rtl8188eu$ sudo make
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.11.0-27-generic/build M=/home/fossiscool/Área de Trabalho/rtl8188eu  modules
make[1]: Entering folder '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-27-generic'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'de'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving folder '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-27-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:155: modules] Erro 2
```

And `sudo make all` gives the same output.

(Translated)

Comment: Rename the `Área de Trabalho` directory to something without spaces in it...

Comment: @steeldriver That looks like an answer. The error pretty much says so: `*** No rule to make target 'de'.`

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you, it worked. If you want you can post this as answer so I can mark that this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `make` build system doesn't deal well with spaces in paths - in this case, it's splitting the assignment

```
M=/home/fossiscool/Área de Trabalho/rtl8188eu
```

into

```
M=/home/fossiscool/Área
```

and then interpreting `de Trabalho/rtl8188eu` as part of the list of targets to be built (hence the error message `*** No rule to make target 'de'.  Stop.`)

The simplest workaround is to rename directory `Área de Trabalho` to something without spaces - such as `Área_de_Trabalho`.